# Android - Set text to TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm currently learning some android for a school project and I can't figure out the way to **set text dynamically** to a `TextView`.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_mensaje);
    err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
    err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
}
```

This is currently not working and I can't find a way to make it work...

Any help will be much appreciated...
Thank you for the time,
José.

EDIT: Here is the **activity_enviar_mensaje.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    tools:context=".EnviarMensaje" >
    ...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listaVista"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listaVista"
        android:text="TextView" />
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

By not working I mean the text shown does not change at any moment...

Comment: what do you mean with `is not working`? If you answer with *is not shown* then please post the XML layout?

Comment: The code you have shown looks fine. Are you getting any errors/crash?

Comment: is `err` declared as a textview? `TextView err;`

Comment: yes, the err is well declared..

Comment: no errors, no crash... I'm starting to think there's something wrong with android in this one

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem, which I am looking into now.

Comment: do you use setContentView only one time? if you use it again after the text update, it will not show the update... you have to use setContentView only one time at the begining

Comment: App-Crazy, please do not post links on their own, as they may 404/403 as yours has.

Comment: i think your textview is hidden by listview

Answer (score 144, accepted):

In your layout XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Escriba el mensaje y luego clickee el canal a ser enviado"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Then, in your activity class:

```
// globally 
TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView);

//in your OnCreate() method
myAwesomeTextView.setText("My Awesome Text");
```

Comment: I got a crash if I set `myAwesomeTextView` globally, because findViewById have to be called in `onCreate`?

Comment: @TimothyLeung : declare the variable to be global , and the call findById in onCreate() only

Comment: You only need to declare it as a field on the class if you want to access it outside of the onCreate() method

Comment: Is it possible to set text withot ID? [My Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64714568/5995648)

Answer (score 24):

**PUT THIS CODE IN YOUR XML FILE**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**PUT THIS CODE IN YOUR JAVA FILE**

***// Declaring components like TextView globally is a good habit***

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

***// Put this in OnCreate***

```
mTextView.setText("Welcome to Dynamic TextView");
```

Answer (score 10):

Well, `@+id/listaVista` ListView is drawn after `@+id/texto` and on top of it. So change in ListView from:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
```

to:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/texto"
```

Also, since the list is drawn after textview, I find it dangerous to have `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listaVista"` in TextView. So remove it and find another way of aligning.

**EDIT**
Taking a second look at your layout I think this is what you really want to have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EnviarMensaje" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Escriba el mensaje y luego clickee el canal a ser enviado"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listaVista"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaVista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the xml given... But unfortunately it didn't solve the original problem... the text view is still showing "TextView" instead of ""Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal."... any ideas???

Comment: @user2471107 Try to remove the text from `TextView` from your layout file and then check. If still doesn't work then post the screenshot of your out put.

Answer (score 8):

In xml use this:

```
<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In Activity define the view:

```
Textview textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_hello));
```

In string file:

```
<string name="txt_hello">Hello</string>
```

Output: Hello

Answer (score 6):

In layout file.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/myTextView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Some Text"
   android:textSize="18sp"
   android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

In Activity

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. It turns out I had two TextView objects with the same ID. They were in different view files and so Eclipse did not give me an error. Try to rename your id in the TextView and see if that does not fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Why don´t you try to assign the textview contents onStart() rather than onCreate()

Answer (score 4):

in your activity_main.xml paste this code:

```
            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/name"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
                 android:text="@string/name" />
```

and go to res folder->values->strings.xml
paste the below code with the code that already exists:

```
          <string name="name">Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.</string>
```

the above code means that you have created a textview with id:name(android:id="@+id/name") and assigned that textview to a string with an identifier name(android:text="@string/name")
in strings.xml your using that identifier name to assign the text,

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
TextView err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Ensure you import TextView.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
TextView.setText("test");
```

Comment: Should be .setText (note the capital "t"\)

Answer (score 3):

Please correct the following line:

```
err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
```

to:

```
err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.err);
```

Answer (score 3):

In XML file,

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="My Name"
       android:textColor="#cccccc"/>
```

In Java Activity file,

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity
 {
   TextView t1;
   public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstance)
      {
         setContentView(R.layout.xmlfilename);
          t1 = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.textview);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> first your should create an object for text view `TextView show_alter`

```
show_alert = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_alert);
show_alert.setText("My Awesome Text");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set string in textview programatically like below.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
```

or

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
err.setText(getActivity().getResource().getString(R.string.seleccione_canal));
```

You can set string in xml like below.

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
         android:text="Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal." />
```

or

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
         android:text="@string/seleccione_canal" />
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have given static text

`err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");`

It will not change , it will remain same.

**Example for Dynamic Text for textview is :**

```
MainActivity.java
package com.example.dynamictextview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int count = 0;
    Button clickMeBtn;
    TextView dynamicText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        clickMeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_click);
        dynamicText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        clickMeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                count++;
                dynamicText.setText("dynamic text example : " + count);

            }
        });

    }

}

For activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dynamictextview.MainActivity" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button_click"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click me"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:layout_below="@id/button_click"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use ButterKnife Library
http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

And use it like

```
@InjectView(R.id.texto)
TextView err;
```

in onCreate method

```
ButterKnife.inject(this)
err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
```

Comment: Why do you suggest a library when a simple native solution suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, you are loading the .xml that contains the `TextView` using `setContentView()`:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_mensaje);
```

and then getting the reference of the TextView inside `activity_enviar_mensaje.xml`, and setting a text:

```
err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
```

The problem is that your TextView is hidden by the `ListView`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know its 2 months but yeah

replace your code

```
Private TextView err;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_mensaje);
    err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
    err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout. Your Texto should not contain (android:text=...). I would remove this line. Either keep the Java string OR the (android:text=...)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your activityMain and set the text by adding a widget from the widgets section and manually changing text by selecting and typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextView err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
```

you can find every thing you need about textview [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Solution

To set using a String, just use this

```
view.text = "My string"
```

To do the same with a resource value, add this extension property to much more easily set your text

```
view.textRes = R.string.my_string

var TextView.textRes
    get() = 0 // HACK: property requires getter
    set(@StringRes textRes) {
        text = resources.getText(textRes)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have assigned the text in onResume() function