# Pass a string to textview

Tags: android, string, textview

I got a string message taken from a php file. And in Android I've specified a generic string value shown below.

```
 private static final String message = " ";
```

How do i get this string value to be shown in the textview in my Android app?

Comment: post your code what you  have tried.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
Textview mytxt=(Textview ) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
mytxt.settext(message );
```

Comment: @ActiveUser if you want to say something else please give details

Answer (score 1):

Putting text to textView (you need to get a hold of reference to TextView):

> textView.setText(message);

More references:
[Android - Set text to TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452269/android-set-text-to-textview)

Answer (score 0):

take text view reference from `findviewbyid`

```
textView.setText(message.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 textViewName.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple try the following code:

```
TextView yourtextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
yourtextview.setText(message );
```