# How to out put a message in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string

I have a `EditText`, where the user will input something, a String.
And then after pressing the bottom, inverting the whole text
and showing it to the user, but, I don't know how to place the String(The inverted text) into
the `TextView`. 
CODE:

```
final EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.escribiraqui); //INPUT
        final TextView T=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.traduccion);         //OUTPUT
        Button TRAD=(Button) findViewById(R.id.traducir);//JUST THE BOTTOM
```

Forget about inverting the text, now I just want to output the same Text(From the EditText to the TextView).

Comment: textView.setText(yourString); ?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan He/She wants to inverting String.

Comment: new StringBuilder(youString).reverse().toString()

Comment: The inverting process is not the problem, just the output of the String(Inverted).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452269/android-set-text-to-textview

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
String mText = text.getText();
text.setText(new StringBuffer(text).reverse().toString());
```

That's it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invert (revert) the String and add it to a TextView you can make a call like this: `myTextView.setText(new StringBuilder(enteredText).reverse().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

If you are newbie then first of all do Googling. This is basic Question, Just Search Like [Inverting string in android](http://bit.ly/1jkd8Hp):

There is solution:

```
return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
```

Place in `TextView` from `EditText` in one line:

```
textView.setText(new StringBuffer(editText.getText().toString()).reverse().toString());
```